# How to change InputTextbox label according to language?

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, dynamic

I am using angular dynamic forms to create a form. I created a form that has only one textbox with dynamic forms. Everything is working perfectly except one. I want to change the textbox label according to the selected language. My textbox label is multilingual in my project but I couldn't assign this multilingual property to the textbox.

Here is my code that creating textbox. In this case label value have to be multilingual.

I am using **ngx-translate** library for multilinguality.

**tr.json =>** `"title": "Unvanlar"`

**en.json =>** `"title": "Titles"`

```
    const inputs: InputBase<any>[] = [
      new InputTextbox({
        key: 'dataValue',
        label: '....',
        type: 'text',
        value: '',
        required: true,
        order: 1
      })
    ];

    return inputs.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
  }
```

label value has to be "Unvanlar" or "Titles" according to website language.

How can I do that? Could you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
private getInputs(): InputBase<any>[] {
    const inputs: InputBase<any>[] = [];

    const textBox = new InputTextbox({
      key: 'titleName',
      label: '',
      type: 'text',
      value: '',
      required: true,
      order: 1
    });

    this.translateService.get(this.labelKeywords).subscribe(
      res => {
        textBox.label = res[this.labelKeywords[0]];
      }
    );

    inputs.push(textBox);

    return inputs.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';`

```
constructor(
   private readonly translate: TranslateService
) {}
```

```
this.translate.get('title').subscribe((title: string) => {
   const inputs: InputBase<any>[] = [
      new InputTextbox({
         key: 'dataValue',
         label: title,
         type: 'text',
         value: '',
         required: true,
         order: 1
      })
   ];
});
```

Something like this should do the trick.

Comment: "not working" how? Getting errors?

Try 
`this.translate.get('title').subscribe((s: any) => {console.log(s);});`


To see what you get

Comment: ```this.translate.instant('title')``` produces **title** result. ```this.translate.get('title').subscribe((s: any) => {console.log(s);});``` produces expected result but I couldn't assign this result to label directly. I want to assign like ```label: this.translate.instant('title')```

Comment: That means the translation isn't loaded when `inputs` is set. I have edited the ansnwer.

Comment: I am returning inputs to assign to a variable. The answer you suggested is working but it doesn't allow return these inputs. I need to be able to return them.

Comment: In that case you can make the method async or make sure the translations are loaded and use `this.translate.instant()`

Comment: I will try DBnR. Thank you.